# Sync lyrics to music in browser

Tags: javascript, web-browser, music, lyrics

I have a song downloaded in MP3 and I have the lyrics in plain text. I would like to create a synced [LRC file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LRC_(file_format)). (Yes, I'm that oldschool). I'm looking for a tool similar to [lrcmaker.com](https://lrcmaker.com/create), but with a bit more features.

I remember that when I did this the last time about a year ago, I found an awesome tool for that – it had simple UI which allowed seeking backwards and forwards in the music and corrections of tagged segments, and all this just using keyboard hotkeys. I believe it was hosted on Github Pages, i.e. at `.github.io`.

*I also think there were some untranslated Japanese characters somewhere and it had some anime background, but that might've changed. That's of course not a requirement I'm asking, just a thing I remember.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! It's [lrc-maker.github.io](https://lrc-maker.github.io). And I found it so randomly, by messing with Firefox extensions and finding the URL in service workers. W00t